# Fixing W3C errors, trying to make website 100% error free

Tags: html, validation

I have just tested my website using the HTML W3C validation service and have received multiple unexpected errors which I am unsure of. I would like to have my page 100% error free and for it to pass the test.

Could you please help me on fixing these errors if you know what they are, as I have no idea that they mean.

1.0 Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
<a href="#home" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a>
```

2.0 End tag div seen, but there were open elements.

```
<img src="images/smalllogo.png" id="smalllogo"></div>
```

3.0 Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
 <li class="nav-dots">
```

4.0 Duplicate ID row.

```
<img src="images/imagepage/200x2001.jpg" id="row">
```

I thought i was allowed to have multiple images with the same ID ??

5.0 The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.

```
<label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
```

Comment: You can not have multiple ANYTHING with the same ID. If you want multiple of something, give it a class instead. ID's are unique.

Comment: You will need to provide more context to the generated HTML code.

Comment: Where is your problem? Don’t you understand the error messages? For example, "Element `a` not allowed as child of element `ul`" seems to be pretty obvious. What is it that you don’t understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1.0 Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context.

```
<a href="#home" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a>
```

You cannot have an `a` element directly underneath a `ul` element. Only `li` elements are allowed directly under a `ul` element.

**Correct:**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Incorrect:**

```
<ul>
  <a href="#home" id="sTop" class="subNavBtn"><li>Home</li></a>
</ul>
```

---

### 2.0 End tag div seen, but there were open elements.

```
<img src="images/smalllogo.png" id="smalllogo"></div>
```

Means you're closing the `div` (or perhaps other) elements incorrectly. I cannot tell you more without seeing your actual code, but be certain you are correctly closing all elements.

---

### 3.0 Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context.

```
 <li class="nav-dots">
```

The `li` element can only exist after a `ul` or `ol` element.

**Correct:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="nav-dots">Something</li>
</ul>
```

**Incorrect:**

```
<div>
  <li class="nav-dots">Something</li>
</div>
```

---

### 4.0 Duplicate ID row.

```
<img src="images/imagepage/200x2001.jpg" id="row">
```

[You may only ever have **ONE** unique `id` on a page.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) If you need to identify several images as `row`, use a `class`.

**Correct:**

```
<img src="images/imagepage/200x2001.jpg" id="image-1" class="row"> 
<img src="images/imagepage/400x4001.jpg" id="image-2" class="row">
```

---

### 5.0 The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control.

```
<label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
```

The `for` attribute on a `label` MUST point to the `id` of a form element.

**Correct:**

```
<label for="name">Name:</label><input type="input" id="name" value="name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1.0 Sounds like your `<a>` tag is directly inside a `<ul>`  it must be first inside a `<li>`

2.0 You closed out your `<div>` with other open tags still inside the element.

3.0 `<li>` needs to be a direct child of `<ul>` or `<ol>` and not of a `<div>`

4.0 you can only use an ID once, you have used it twice, use a class instead.

5.0 `<label>` is to be used inside of a `<form>` element it appears you have used it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

1.0 Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) - You are trying to nest an element within another element that does not accept that element as a child, for example, `<a>` inside `<head>`

2.0 End tag div seen, but there were open elements. - You forgot to close an element before closing its parent container. In this case, it's that `<img>` tag that you are using that isn't closed.

3.0 Element li not allowed as child of element div in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) - `<li>` needs to be inside of `<ul>`.

4.0 Duplicate ID row. - IDs MUST be unique. You cannot use duplicate IDs.

5.0 The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control. - What element is the `for` attribute referencing? It needs to be a form element. (`input`, `select`, etc.)